# Serial communication stops when I connect the tx cable

Tags: serial, rf

I'm using the apc220 rf modules. Now I'm having the following problem:

My receiving arduino uno only receives data when the tx pin on the arduino (rx pin on the rf module) is disconnected. As soon as I connect the tx pin my serial monitor receives only the value 0.

Is my rf module broken, or can someone help me with this?

Comment: Which Arduino board are you using?

Comment: The Uno only has a single hardware UART. Are you attempting to use it to connect to both the USB-UART bridge and the RF module at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

To have two serial ports on Arduino board like Uno use `SoftwareSerial.h`.

Example

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);


  Serial.println("Hello!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Now after opening `Serial monitor` you should see Hello! and then you can test `SoftwareSerial`.

**DO NOT FORGET!!!**

When you connect to pins 2,3 or etc, this is **TTL** voltage level. You **can't** connect direct to RS232.

Comment: I know about Software Serial. The problem is that I use the rf modules for a quadcopter project and I need the memory of the rx pin, I think (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Ok, so if you know more than i expected :) Clear for me this: How you connect RF module and debug it at the same time having only 1 serial port? Remember that : pins 0 and 1 ar Tx, Rx for USB. You can use them only without USB attached

Comment: And yes it takes more than memory. I would go for HW serial. replacing with Mega maybe

Comment: Haha, I'm starting to know arduino bit by bit. :) Whem I'm uploading the code I always disconnect the rf module. After uploading the code I connect the rf module again. If I open the serial monitor it seems to work on 1 serial port. But I just ordered my arduino Mega because the serial communication is a big pain in the ass with the uno... :)